# IIS 6 Not allowing me to properly redirect to custom 404 Not Found HTML page

Tags: html, css, iis, http-status-code-404, iis-6

I am hoping that there is a simple **code-free** solution. Using IIS 6, I've set my custom error "/notfound.html" page as an absolute URL in the primary directory of the site. It works perfectly if I put in something like:

*www.mysite.com/bananas.html **or** www.mysite.com/bananas*

But if I were to go navigate 1-2 folders deeper, it'll point to that page (in the deeper directory though) but will disregard the navigation structure/relative linking and styling (css/js that I'm pointing to):

*www.mysite.com/about/bananas.html*

Will display the HTML page but in the Wrong location, if that makes sense. I wanted to see if there's a more reasonable solution to redirect to the file, and make sure it's in the top directory/folder without having to add any additional coding or if there's an easy enough workaround for this.

Thanks in advance, everyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've resolved this, I needed to put Native links (instead of relative links) throughout the customized 404 HTML page (css, js, nav links, etc). That fixed it!